# How to add an interface realization to a base class ( List<t>)

Tags: c#

I have an interface  IPooledObject which is needed for object to  be pooled properly.

Yet I can't seem to find a way to add this "support" on List.

The point of using interface and not inheritance is simply because it is easier to add support for the pooling system  on an existing project.

I don't want to lose that perk.

Tl dr;  How should I proceed to make List implement the interface IPooledObject ?

Comment: Have you considered implementing an adapter?

Comment: I'd prefer not since it's for an existing project i would like this to be plug en play and not have to rewrite constructors everywhere :s

Comment: Wrap a list in your class which implements `IPooledObject` or inherit the list and implement `IPooledObject`?

Comment: As said, i would prefer not to hide list inside another class. Id like to "extend" it's functionality

Comment: @Fawar So go for inheriting it. I don't understand what stops you doing it?

Comment: Because that would mean rechecking/changing reference in more than 500 files to support pooling (from List to NewList). While interface allows me to add my 2-3 functions inside of List<t> and object pooling would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend List with extension method. It'll look like this:

```
public static class PoolingExtensions
{
    public static void PoolObject<T>(this List<T> source, T item)
    {
        //do something to pool object properly
    }
}
```

But, ofc, this is not interface implementation. If you want to implement both, you'll need to make a derived class

Comment: That could work, the interface will be used for custom classes and base classes could be extended this way

Comment: Ill keep it open a bit longer to see if anyone comes out with other solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without inheriting the `List<T>` class.

```
public YourList<T> : List<T>, IPoolObject
{
}
```

Depending of the purpose of the interface, you could also opt to use extension methods (note only *methods* are possible here):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void YourMethod(this IList objectToPool)
    {
    }

    // or if you prefer this:
    public static void YourMethod<T>(this List<T> objectToPool)
    {
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
yourList.YourMethod();
```

Comment: This is a solution to the general problem, but not to mine.
I really need not to swap every list reference/object to a new class and eventually I would need to do this for dictionnaries to and so on ...etc

Comment: Which of the two solutions?

Comment: By the way, you could opt for a simple 'ReplaceAll' on the name of the class, but that is up to you.

Comment: Ohh sorry missed the extension part which was already brought up by @Alex

Comment: BTw it should be List<t> and not IList I think?

Comment: Possibly, I prefer IList since it reads easier. But List<T> is okay too.

Comment: Care to elaborate why it's better in Ilist? I'm curious

Comment: It isn't better, but if you aren't going to narrow down `T`, using `List<T>` doesn't add that much. I have some custom implementations of `IList` running here, so that's why I tend to use the least I need.